# Stuck too early in local minima with tabu and simulated annealing

Tags: optaplanner, timetable

Trying to generate the Roster of employees however going doing at the level of hour. Resource hour requirements are like 1h at 8, 2 at 9, 7 at 1pm..

After assigning the first 3 resources, it keeps checking solutions are around them via assigning/reassigning them to Slots without trying to assign other employees.

How to troubleshoot this problem? couldn't it be the weights for each constraint/violation? Does it speed it if I implement a quick construction heuristic that fills the slots before handing to local search?

Current configuration consists of first_fit for construction heuristic, hill climbing as first phase till it get stuck then tabu with simulated annealing

Answer (score 0):

Normally a CH assigns all employees before LS starts, which just moves them around but never unassigns anyone. See general phase sequence diagram in chapter "optimization algorithms" in the docs. That's presuming you don't apply overconstrained planning (nullable=true or null in the value range).

If you do apply overconstrained planning, that you need to make sure that the score cost of leaving an employee unassigned is worse than the score cost of however he's could be assigned.

Also set up a benchmarker config, so you have some benchmark report graphs to allow you to understand what's going on.